# Bootstrap panel full linking

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Can someone help my with this problem;

http://www.bootply.com/eN40Ko2uua

I have a navigation system made from the panel collaps, but the only part you can click on is the word while I would like the whole panel to link.

But if I place the  and  around the td it doesn't work, 
if I put it around the div the design changes what I don't want neither:
http://www.bootply.com/10tPocupPp

Does someone have a solution for this problem to let the menu, submenu be clickable around the whole width/height.

Comment: Use this `.panel-heading { padding:0;}
.panel-title a { 
   display: block; 
   padding: 10px 15px; }`, may this is what you want.

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay Exactlly, how to get it also on the submenu ?

Comment: the `toggle` functionality is based on `<a>` but since its `display: inline-block` and its parent has `padding` which covers full area, so just reset its *CSS* and change it as I've done for the parent.

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay thanks for your answer, but unfortunately I had to reverse all the changes because the other panel titles on my pages had their design changed were I didn't want to, how can I solve this? Thanks in adventage!

Comment: Never change the default *bootstrap* classes, instead of that make your custom container with any className, then relating to that alter your navigation `panel-heading`.